# Difference Between Rows and fill Columns

Tags: python, text, python-2.5, subtraction

I have a text file that contains:

```
Week OrangeTotal ODifference AppleTotal ADifference
1        2            -         3          -
2        5            ?         4          ?
3        10           ?         10         ?
4        50           ?         100        ?
```

I would like it to skip the first line since it's the start of the new year, but fill in the column next to it with the subtraction of that row and the row below.

It should be:

```
Week OrangeTotal ODifference AppleTotal ADifference
1        2            -         3          -
2        5            3         4          1
3        10           5         10         6
4        50          40         100        90
```

Comment: That's nice! What did you try, where did you get stuck? Where is your code so that we can help you fix the problems you faced.

Comment: Also please take some time to go through your previous questions and [accept some answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem.

Comment: I might use regex replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os


def main():
    name = 'log.txt'
    tmpName = 'tmp.txt'
    f = open(name, 'r')
    tmp = open(tmpName, 'w')

    titleLine = f.readline().strip()
    tmp.write(titleLine+'\n')

    prevLine = f.readline().strip()
    tmp.write(prevLine+'\n')
    prevLine = prevLine.split('\t')

    for line in f:
        line = line.split('\t')
        line[2] = str(int(line[1]) - int(prevLine[1]))
        line[4] = str(int(line[3]) - int(prevLine[3]))
        prevLine = line

        displayLine=''
        for i in range(len(line)-1):
            displayLine += line[i]+'\t'
        displayLine += line[len(line)-1]

        tmp.write(displayLine+'\n')

    f.close()
    tmp.close()
    os.remove(name)
    os.rename(tmpName, name)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

import sys

ds = open("Path.txt",'r').readlines()
a = list()
b = list()
for words in ds[1:]:
    a.append(words)
for words in ds:
    b.append(words)

for lines in a:
    again = int(lines)
    for words in b:
        bse = int(words)
        print bse-again
```

Comment: Please give an explanation re: how this solves the original question.

Answer (score 0):

so far I think it may be easier for you to work with each line in a for loop like `for lines in ds[1:]:` loop. it is also important to note that readlines produces an array of the lines of the file.
So `ds[0]` =`'Week OrangeTotal ODifference AppleTotal ADifference'`

so you need to loop over the lines

```
old=0 # this is to store the last value
done = list()
for i in range(1, len(ds), 1):      #[range()][1]
   l=0 # we define l here so that the garbage collector does not decide we no longer need it
   if(old!=0):          #if this is not the first one
       l = ds[i].split()    
                        # [split()][2] gets rid of whitespace and turns it into a list
       for v in range(1, 3, 2): 
              #we skip the first value as that is the week and then next as that is the answer
          ds[v+1] = ds[v] - old[v] #here is where we do the actual subtraction and store the value
   old = l #when we are done we set the row we finished as old
   done[i] = l.join("    ")
   print(str(done[i]))
```

what you do with this from here is your decision